# Element is not clicking on click in python selenium webdriver in Odoo

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, odoo

there is a list field which I have sticked with an image

[image]

Here after clicking on the list , I have to select first option that is Cash(EUR)
I have written a code in python by xpath that is ,

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//Select[@name='journal_id']/option[normalize-space(text())='Cash (EUR)']").click()
```

from this code , it will let me select that perticular element but not able to click on that element instead of writing click()

So , whats the exact code ? or give me specific code so that I will be able to click on that element

Comment: Do you actually want to test the `change()` event of the option field?

Comment: Are you sure you have managed to select an element? It looks like you are using an upper case `S` in `Select` instead of a lower case one

Comment: I have imported the library called : `from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import unittest` . Hence it is running

Comment: No , sir , I want to click on that element that is selected by this code , i used click() method over here , but here it will let me to that element but can't able to click it , I want to click the fetched element

Answer (score 0):

You should use here selenium select command, instead of click. as it is drop down not clickable element.

Answer (score 0):

It may be done by this that first I focus on that list box on which I have to select cash option then I will search an element by keyboard by send_key method & in which I will enter work for ex. Cash , then this process will run automatically like we select an element just like entering their name by a keyboard

```
a=browser.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/span/select")
    a.send_keys("Cash (EUR)")
```

It works :)
Here it will automatically select cash option by not going options view